# Why do I got errors on Gradle when creating a new Project on Android Studio 2.2.1?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to create a new Blank Project on Android Studio 2.1.1, but when it finishes to load the new project it gave me an error:

> Gradle project sync completed with some errors. Open the 'Message' view to see the errors found.

And then, the errors that I got are the following:

[image: Errors that I got from gradle]

Here are my specs:

- Windows 8
- Java 1.8
- Android Studio 2.2.1

I'm behind a proxy.

Comment: You can try teaching Android Studio about the proxy. From the main menu, choose File > Settings. In there, go into Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > HTTP Proxy, and configure the proxy. Then, try re-syncing the Gradle build files.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks for trying to help me! I've already tried this, but no success! It still giving me same errors...I don't know what to do anymore...

Comment: OK, I hoped that Android Studio would pass those values to Gradle, but perhaps not. Next, try [Gradle's instructions for configuring a proxy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare, actually Android Studio did pass the Values to Gradle properties...I checked it...But it still not work...

Comment: Then I suggest that you talk to whoever manages your network and ask them for assistance. Your Android Studio and Gradle do not appear to be able to reach the JCenter artifact repository.